# The rear gears(Shifter) are stuck on 7

Tags: gears

So while I was taking my bicycle out of the elevator, it closes its doors(The elevator does not have sensors rather it has the mechanism which keeps the door open if you push a flap between the inner and outer door) and hits the gears after which it refuses to shift. No part broke off or anything and its a new cycle (3 days old). Please help....

Comment: Sounds like the doors hit the rear wheel and the derailleur on the right hand side.  Can you please post a clear photo of what it looks like ?

Comment: It could have snapped the cable or forced it out of a poorly-tightened adjuster.  Does the lever feel stiff, loose, or normal?

Comment: There are a half-dozen possibilities.  The derailer or the "hanger" to which it's attached may have  been bent, the cable may have been bent right where it enters the derailer, the chain may have been pushed off the jockey wheels, etc.  Requires observation by a knowledgeable person.

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear, for now, but I'll happily retract that or vote to reopen if the question is clarified. clear photos of the rear derailleur from several angles (at a minimum, from the side and from behind) are pretty much necessary, here.

Comment: @albert please use the "edit" link under your question, to add the extra info and pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Without a picture of your bike, there's nothing anyone here can help you with, so here's what you should do: take your bike back to the shop. If it's new and under warranty, you may get away with a free fix. However, since this damage is totally unrelated to the intended use of the bike, you'll probably have to pay for repairs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to fix this yourself? If yes then the impacts on your drivetrain can be troubleshooted with the following steps.

1. Visually inspect that the cable moves freely from the shifter all the way to the derailleur. The cable should glide effortlessly in it's housing all the way to the derailleur. If not you need to spot where is the friction coming from.
2. Make sure that the cable routing is not damaged. All the cable routing points should be straight and solidly attached to the frame.
3. Make sure that your derailleur can move freely through it's range. You can do this by removing the back wheel and pulling on the cable. Things should move smoothly. If not your derailleur is damaged and you need a new one.
4. Make sure that your limit screws are properly set so that your bike shifts on all the gears without having the chain fall off.
5. Adjust the top jockey wheel distance to the cassette according to your derailleur requirement. This varies by manufacturer so you need to look it up.
6. Your derailleur might have had it's hanger bent. The only way to fix this is if you have the park tool DAG-2 tool and perform the alignment procedure.

Only adjust one thing at a time to make sure you understand the impact of what you did on the drive train. Try to shift pedal and shift the gears every time you adjust something.